# how to change a Css Style Class definition with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to override the Css Classes with JavaScript ?
for exemple :

Adding a background to .iframe style classe.

Comment: indeed it is, thanks

Comment: Do you mean changing the background for _all elements that have the `iframe` class_? Just toggle another class name for those elements and define a CSS rule with the background for only that toggled class.

Answer (score -1):

### Who is the troll

who down voted my answer?
Please provide your reason

---

Changing a STYLE property

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('.iframe');
iframe.style['marginBottom'] = "200px";
```

Changing a CLASS property

```
iframe['className'] = "myClass";
```

Comment: Didn't down vote but see e duplicate question what this was really about.